# Kubuntu 18.04 no desktop and taskbar

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, desktop-environments

right after I just ditched GNOME with tasksel (which I found out it's not ok to remove it) I installed by `apt-get`, `kubuntu-desktop`, everything works fine but the desktop and my touchpad.

I don't have taskbar, folders, I really don't get it on how to interact with it, have I done something wrong?

The problem with my touchpad is that I can't click, but I can scroll and wave my cursor around.

Comment: @DKBose it says plasma

Comment: @DKBose it's totally a problem, I got my laptop back from sleep and my screen is not on but the fan is working

Comment: Is it possible to do a clean reinstall without deleting my system or something?

Comment: @DKBose everything is backed up but i was just wondering if i can do a purge then an install or something

Comment: @DKBose so I can't just purge kubuntu-desktop then install it again?

Comment: What is your objection to doing a totally new install given all the issues you've faced with the existing system?

Comment: Yeah you're right, I'll just get kubuntu